# Como pegar a data mais distante no MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Tenho as seguintes tabelas

```
             boi
-------------------------------
id | peso |    data_pesagem   | 
-------------------------------
1  | 175  |     2019-01-02    |
2  | 200  |     2019-01-03    |
-------------------------------


         boi_manejo
---------------------------
fk_boi | peso |    data   | 
---------------------------
   1   | 213  | 2019-02-05|
   2   | 222  | 2019-02-03|
   1   | 213  | 2019-01-20|
   2   | 222  | 2019-01-29|
---------------------------
```

Como eu posso buscar facilmente a data mais distante do boi ID 1 na tabela manejo, em relação à data de pesagem dele na primeira tabela, por exemplo?

Comment: `select fk_boi, max( data ) from boi_manejo group by fk_boi`?

Comment: E se eu quiser usar essa função numa cláusula Where?

Comment: Assim?  `select * from boi_manejo where max( data ) > alguma_data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ordene seus resultados pela diferença entre a data da tabela `boi` e a data da tabela `boi_manejo`. Depois disso limite o número de resultados a apenas um.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE boi (
  id           INTEGER,
  peso         NUMERIC(15, 2),
  data_pesagem DATE
);

INSERT INTO boi(id, peso, data_pesagem)
        VALUES (1, 175, '2019-01-02'),
               (2, 200, '2019-01-03');

CREATE TABLE boi_manejo (
  fk_boi INTEGER,
  peso   NUMERIC(15, 2),
  data   DATE
);

INSERT INTO boi_manejo(fk_boi, peso, data)
               VALUES (1, 213, '2019-02-05'),
                      (2, 222, '2019-02-03'),
                      (1, 213, '2019-01-20'),
                      (2, 222, '2019-01-29');
```

---

**Query**

```
SELECT b.id,
       bm.peso,
       bm.data
  FROM boi b
 INNER JOIN boi_manejo bm ON bm.fk_boi = b.id
 WHERE b.id = 1
 ORDER BY DATEDIFF(b.data_pesagem, bm.data) DESC
 LIMIT 1;
```

**Resultando em**

```
| id  | peso | data       |
| --- | ---- | ---------- |
| 1   | 213  | 2019-01-20 |
```

---

Veja funcionando no [**DB Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nvrA6d25vhJ3MhqmK4v2J3/0).

---

> [`DATEDIFF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)
>
> returns `expr1 − expr2` expressed as a value in days from one date to the other.

Em tradução livre:

> retorna `expr1 − expr2` como um valor em dias de uma data para a outra.

Comment: Obrigado @Sorack. Utilizei isso na query e consegui pegar o peso. Tudo de bom!